# Redirecting to an annotation after pressing a table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mobile, apple-maps

I have incorporated a search bar in a map that displays different results of specific pins that are placed on the map. I am trying to redirect the user to a specific pin when he taps a table view cell. Unfortunately I get this error:

"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

on the line:

`self.VC.LiveMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)`

Code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    private var tableView: UITableView!
    var filteredOffices = [OfficeStats]()
    var filteredNames = [String]()
    
    var VC = ViewController()
    let searchBar = UISearchBar()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        sortList()
        setUpNavBar()
        searchBar.delegate = self
        filteredOffices = VC.officesCopy
        
        VC.retrieveNameCopy() { (success, filteredOffices) in
            if success {
                self.VC.sortList()
            } else {
                print("unsuceess")
            }
        }
        let barHeight = view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
        let displayWidth: CGFloat = self.view.frame.width
        let displayHeight: CGFloat = self.view.frame.height
        
        tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: barHeight, width: displayWidth, height: displayHeight - barHeight))
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        
    }
    
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.text = ""
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        filteredOffices = []

        if searchText == "" {
            filteredOffices = VC.officesCopy
        }
        else{
            for offices in VC.officesCopy {
                
                if offices.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()){
                    filteredOffices.append(offices)
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(filteredOffices.count)
        return filteredOffices.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        dismiss(animated: true)
        print(filteredOffices[indexPath.count])
        let geoPoint = filteredOffices[indexPath.count].coordinates
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: geoPoint.latitude, longitude: geoPoint.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.005, longitudeDelta: 0.005))            
        self.VC.LiveMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredOffices[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = filteredOffices[indexPath.row].location
        return cell
    }
    
    
    func setUpNavBar() {
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = .prominent
        searchBar.placeholder = "Kërko"
        searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
        searchBar.isTranslucent = true
    }
}
```

Comment: `self.VC` is just a view controller instance that you have created in your search controller.  It wasn't created from a storyboard so none of its outlets are set and even if it was created from a storyboard it wouldn't be the instance that is in screen.  You need to pass a reference to the actual vc instance that has your onscreen map to the search controller.

Comment: @Paulw11 On my View Controller I have created an IBOutlet for the storyboard to connect to the LiveMap. 
Can you help me on how to do that?

Comment: How do you get from your map view controller to the search controller?  It is during that process that you get the reference you need